# Combine Arrays in Order JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a few arrrays which I am trying to combine in a certain order.  For example, lets say I have three arrays:

```
var arrayOne = [1a, 1b, 1c];
var arrayTwo = [2a, 2b, 2c];
var arrayThree [3a, 3b, 3c];
```

how would I get something like this?

```
var combinedArray = [1a, 2a, 3a, 1b, 2b, 3b, 1c, 2c, 3c]
```

*EDIT*

Ok, I am going to add a little more to my story here since I have gotten some great responses and answers from everyone.  Maybe this will be clearer.  I have a SharePoint list which I am getting all of my information from.  I am using SPServices to get my data from the list.  I am also getting the version history of each list item and placing them into arrays so I can pull the data out of the SPServices loop and use it outside of the SharePoint stuff so I can try to order and display it as I want.  (Please do not move this to SharePoint ).
This is all going to have to happen at runtime.  So here is the first part.  I am declaring global variables for each one of my list items:

```
var proModified6 = new Array();
var proHistory = new Array();
var assignedTo = new Array();
var startDate = new Array();
var endDate = new Array();
var status = new Array();
var project = new Array();
var history = new Array();


var listItems = new Array();


var regex = new RegExp("");

var i = 0;
```

Then I am filling the arrays with the SharePoint list info ( I am not going to put them all but each has a call like this one)

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetVersionCollection",
      async: false,
      webURL: "http://devchrisl01/test",
      strlistID: "NewProjects",
      strlistItemID: proID[i],
      strFieldName: "Title",         

      completefunc: function (xdata, Status) {

        $(xdata.responseText).find("Version").each(function() {

       //alert(xdata.responseXML.xml);

       var xitem = $(this);
            var ID = xitem.attr('ID');
            var Project = xitem.attr('Title');
            var Modified = xitem.attr('Modified').split('T')[0];
            var ModifiedTime = xitem.attr('Modified').substring(11, 19);
           //var modifiedUl = "<td><b>" + Modified + " " + ModifiedTime + "</b></td>";
  //$('#versionList'+i+'').append(modifiedUl);

                  project.push(Project);
                  proModified2.push(Modified + ModifiedTime)


    // just looking at my data here not really part of my problem       
var data = "<tr><td><b>" + Modified + " " + ModifiedTime + "</b></td><td>" + Project + "</td></tr>";


$('#versionList'+i+'').append(data);

        });  

      }

});
```

After is where my question has come into play.  I am getting all of my data back I need.  I have not found a better way to store all of the list information and pull it out of the SPServices besides using an array for each.  The kicker is I am not going to know how many arrays there are going to be or how long.  Eventually this is going to be dynamic. (PAIN IN THE ASS )  so here are the arrays:

```
var modifiedDate = [proModified1, proModified2, proModified3, proModified4, proModified5, proModified6];
var projectHistory = [history];
var projectTitle = [project];
var projectAssignedTo = [assignedTo];
var projectStartDate = [startDate];
var projectEndDate = [endDate];
var projectStatus = [status];
```

Each one is going to be different.  There is not going to be the same amount of them either for each user.  I have just made my list static to build on first.  List dynamics will be another question later :0

Is there going to be a way for me to do with these arrays like I asked in my simple example?  See why I went simple first lol.

Comment: Will array lengths be always same? Here it is 3 for example

Comment: No some will be smaller or larger depending on entries.  I am getting the array data based off of a sharepoint list.  each one of the arrays I am using represents the version of each item.  So when it is handed to the users I will have no idea how many items will be in each array.  kinda long explination :) just trying to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.  Thanks

Comment: what do you expect to happen if the arrays were different lengths... can you give an example?

Comment: I was trying to get simple with this because what I am doing is a little complex.  I was trying to not get into too much of what I was doing.  Sorry for being vague.  What I would like is a blank value or undefined would be ok.  I know my problem is going to be not knowing the length of the array.  Welcome to my nightmare.  I was hoping if I could get them organized I would be able to sort them.  That is why my question is so simple let’s say.  If I have too I will put my stuff in here with an edit but it will be moved to SharePoint I know it.  Thanks for all of the quick responses.

Comment: I am going to edit and repost to this with more detail about what I am doing.  It is in SharePoint but my problem is with the arrays and not SharePoint so maybe they will not move it.

Comment: @lazoDev We need to see the actual data to better understand what it is? Also if you want to simply merge all those arrays then use `.concat`, if you want to sort see custom comparator as in my answer and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10305127/297641). I think, you have all the clues you need to solve the problem. Please post a specific question as you had initially.

Comment: Thanks fo ryou time on the Vega, but the data is not going to matter because in the end, I am not going to know what the data is going to be.  This is going to load dynamically.  I know how I am going to do that I just need to see if there is a good way to organize these arrays,  I think what you posted is going to be the closes and I am going to play with it to see if I can get some type of facsimile  of it to work for my situation.  Thanks for your time on this sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Updated comparator as Salmon pointed out that it should return `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Try below,

```
var arrayOne = ["1a", "1b", "1c"];
var arrayTwo = ["2a", "2b", "2c"];
var arrayThree = ["3a", "3b", "3c"];

var combinedArray = arrayOne
    .concat(arrayTwo, arrayThree) //Concatenate the array.. can add any number of arrays
    .sort(function(a, b) { //Custom comparator for your data
       var a1 = a.charAt(1);
       var b1 = b.charAt(1);

       if (a1 == b1) return 0;
       if (a1 < b1) return -1;
       return 1;
    });
```

**Note:** The custom comparator function is very specific to your data. Update the function as you need.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/NzuBL/3/)

Comment: your code should produce `xa,ya,za,xb,yb,zb,xc,yc,zc` with this values http://jsfiddle.net/NzuBL/1/ but it returns `xa,xb,xc,ya,yb,yc,za,zb,zc`

Comment: @ajax333221 Did you read the Note?? Did OP mention that data in his post? Did you downvote because it failed for something that OP never asked for?

Comment: I am afraid the specific data was probably made-up data, not something that OP will actually be working upon.

Comment: @Vega everyone makes mistakes, I now undownvoted, but I think that is not what OP wants. (but it works for that particular data values)

Comment: @ajax333221 No problem, thanks for leaving a comment.. most time, people just downvote and disappear which really doesn't help in anyways.

Comment: This works great for the simple data, and like I said up top, sorry to be vague.  I seem to get better responses on here when I do not try to put too much into a problem up vote for the response it works.

Comment: Bunch of things, 1. `.join` is for `console.log` and 2. What you have is based on the order of data that is already there and it may not work if the order change or length of array is different. 3. Ofcourse the sort is going to be slower than what you have as you are just pushing data in specific order without comparision.

Comment: @Vega: this may or may not work!!! `array.sort()` must return a +/- number or 0. You're returning 0 or 1, not returning -1 if `a1 < b1` (ii) when you remove the numbers from strings you end up with 3xa, 3xb, 3xc. Even if you get the return value right, array.sort is free to put `3a` before `1a` because you're checking for `a = a`. It works but it works by accident. -1.

Comment: @Vega the answer I included was my slower one (I did some checks to prevent undefined values), about the test, I will update the `.join` thing, I am use it will still be around x4 times faster. I think I will downvote: Reasons: readability and slow performance

Comment: @ajax333221 As mentioned earlier, You need to compare Apple with Apple. Your comparison is not valid. Your code doesn't sort, You simply push data in specific position based on the order. The above use sorting and sorting is slow... And I completely disagree with readability.

Comment: @Vega it is valid to compare apples with oranges when you are deciding which one to give to someone. If it is slow, why you used it?

Comment: @ajax333221 It is again debatable and It is OP who can decide if he wants an apple or orange. Will your code work if OP wants to sort data after he merged all array? And again it is an assumption and There are pro's and con's in each implementation and OP is the only one who can choose which suits his requirements and [You definitely should read this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: @Vega I read that link, and I downvoted on the least useful from my point of view, it is slow and OP never said anything of sorting (use ctrl+f and type "sor" and the first word is in your ans). I think my dv is perfectly fine. Also it is not because I want my ans to be accepted (I even upvoted another ans here)

Comment: ahhhh what about my question???  Thanks for your answers but if you guys want to argue code email each other lol.

Answer (score 2):

If the length of the three arrays will always be the same of each other:

```
var arrayOne = ["1a", "1b", "1c"];
var arrayTwo = ["2a", "2b", "2c"];
var arrayThree = ["3a", "3b", "3c"];

var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arrayOne.length; i < len; i++) {
    newArray.push(arrayOne[i], arrayTwo[i], arrayThree[i]);
}

console.log(newArray); //1a,2a,3a,1b,2b,3b,1c,2c,3c
```

But if your arrays won't always be the same length, we will need to use the greatest length of the three arrays and skip missing indexes, so it will be like this:

```
var arrayOne = ["1a", "1b", "1c", "1d"];
var arrayTwo = ["2a", "2b", "2c"];
var arrayThree = ["3a", "3b"];

var newArray = [];
var len = Math.max(arrayOne.length, arrayTwo.length, arrayThree.length);

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i in arrayOne) {
        newArray.push(arrayOne[i]);
    }
    if (i in arrayTwo) {
        newArray.push(arrayTwo[i]);
    }
    if (i in arrayThree) {
        newArray.push(arrayThree[i]);
    }
}

console.log(newArray); //1a,2a,3a,1b,2b,3b,1c,2c,1d
```

The reason to use `i in arr` (as difference of other checks), is because this will allow you to keep any falsish value `0,"",false,null,undefined,NaN` intact. Otherwise it will be very hard to leave them alone (specially `undefined` values inside your array)

[Performance tests](http://jsperf.com/arraymerge/3) between my answer and the currently most upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304998/908879)

Comment: this pushes "undefined" if the array lengths differ... consider adding some checks

Comment: You post worked with my stuff so thanks; however, it is still returning 1a,1b,1c,2a,2b....and so on for my code.  Understand I used the simple question with made up data to try to explain as simple as I could.  What you did  does work just not how I need it thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you're looking for a `zip` function, like [in python](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip). There's no such built-in in javascript, but it's easy to write, for example:

```
zip = function() {
    var 
        args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0),
        len = Math.max.apply(Math, args.map(function(x) { return x.length })),
        out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        out.push(args.map(function(x) { return x[i] }));
    return out;
}
```

Applied to your arrays

```
var arrayOne = ["1a", "1b", "1c"];
var arrayTwo = ["2a", "2b", "2c"];
var arrayThree = ["3a", "3b", "3c"];

zipped = zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

this creates a nested array:

```
[["1a", "2a", "3a"], ["1b", "2b", "3b"], ["1c", "2c", "3c"]]
```

which you can use as is or convert to a flat one:

```
 flat = [].concat.apply([], zipped)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the default JS `sort()` method with a callback of some kind. If the elements if the array are all like `/[0-9][a-z]/`, this will give you the desired result:

```
//concat arrays first, of course
function specialSort(a,b)
{
    if(a[1] < b[1])
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if(a[1] > b[1])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
//using wsanville's expample: combinedArray = ["1a", "1b", "1c", "2a", "2b", "2c", "3a", "3b", "3c"]
combinedArray = combinedArray.sort(specialSort);
//result: combinedArray = ["1a", 2a", "3a", "1b", "2b", "3b", "1c", "2c", "3c"]
```

Hope this works for you...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
var arrayOne = ["1a", "1b", "1c"];
var arrayTwo = ["2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "2e"];
var arrayThree = ["3a", "3b", "3c", "3d"];
var combinedArray = [];

for (var i = 0, j = Math.max(arrayOne.length, arrayTwo.length, arrayThree.length); i < j; i++) {
    if (arrayOne.length) combinedArray.push(arrayOne.shift());
    if (arrayTwo.length) combinedArray.push(arrayTwo.shift());
    if (arrayThree.length) combinedArray.push(arrayThree.shift());
}

alert(combinedArray.join(", "));​
```

This should probably work for variable length arrays. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gEJMt/2/).

Comment: +1, although that is modifying the original 3 arrays, but this should not be a problem